# I need to move my MySQL database to a network drive, currently on a free web host account

Tags: mysql

I have been working on an internship project and I built a database but I have been doing it under a free hosting website using their PhpMyAdmin. That is very insecure for our data to go to,  so I need to transfer the database to my company's network drive so that the data wont be going to the free hosting website, instead it could be on our network. Meanwhile we are waiting for our own sub-domain, but that takes a long time and we will need the site on a temp domain. Is there any way that I can install MySQL directly to my drive? Any instructions or tutorial? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/78378-possible-have-mysql-data-mapped-network-drive  might be helpful

Comment: Really really bad idea. You'd be much better off investigating a replicated or clustered configuration.

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL needs to be installed on a server. If you need to stick to a netowrk drive, you could look into [SQLite]: http://www.sqlite.org/ . It doesn't need to be installed and it portable since it just a file. Depending on the way you wrote your queries, you might need to adjust some syntax when swtiching to sqlite.

Comment: :/ I have about 50 pages of php already, would that be an overkill? I don't want it to take me ages redoing everything

Comment: were you using mysql, mysqli, PDO? also was it written in procedural or OOP?

Comment: just pure mysql im not sure what procedural or oop means

Comment: `mysql_query` is becoming depreciated, so for the future I'd switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` . Depending on how youre code is written it could be just modifying your connection method to rewriting everything. Take a look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php it should help out, to see how much you'll have

Comment: Does your company not have a MYSQL server you could use? If they do, then its just as simple as creating a copy of the database

Comment: No they use SQL not MySQL

Comment: Unfortunely, you'll need to rewrite code in either case.